# having an issue converting fractions to double

Tags: java, class, oop, driver

For some reason I've been unable to print a fraction as a double. I can't get past it. It gives formatting errors every time. The parts giving me issues are commented. Class and driver code are below. and help is appreciated.

Class code

```
public class Fraction1
{
    private int numerator;     
    private int denominator;   

    public void Fraction1(int n, int d)
    {
        this.numerator = n;
        this.denominator = d;
    } 

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(numerator + "/" + denominator);
    }

    public Fraction1 add(Fraction1 other)
    {
        int n = this.numerator * other.denominator +
        this.denominator * other.numerator;
        int d = this.denominator * other.denominator;
        return this;
    }

    //public void printAsDouble()
    //{
    //  this.printAsDouble();
    //  System.out.println((double)(numerator)/(double)                (denominator));
    //}
}
```

Driver code

```
import java.util.*;

public class FractionDriver1
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Fraction c, d, x;    
        x = new Fraction();

        System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator.");
        c = new Fraction(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
        c.print();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator.");
        d = new Fraction(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
        d.print();

        System.out.println("Sum:");
        x.add(c).add(d);
        x.print();
        //x.printAsDouble();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by formatting errors? What do you see? What do you expect to see?

Comment: The issues I can see are that `public void Fraction1(int n, int d)` should probably be `public Fraction1(int n, int d)` (a constructor does not return `void`) and you shouldn't have a recursive call `this.printAsDouble();`.

Comment: it runs just fine up until the print as double. it compiles and everything. the error I receive is - illegal format conversion exception. and then it has a great big list of what I assume are jvm errors.

Comment: Can you post that great big list in the question?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f !=java.lang.Integer

Comment: at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302) at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806) at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753) at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520) at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970) at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871) at Fraction.printAsDouble(Fraction.java:36) at FractionDriver1.main(FractionDriver1.java:31)

Comment: The code you have shown us can't possibly produce that exception because you aren't using `printf`. Also your code doesn't compile because `Fraction1` doesn't have a constructor taking 2 `int` values. You won't get a decent answer unless you show us the actual code you are using.

Comment: agreed with @pbabcdefp

Comment: at `FractionDriver1.main(FractionDriver1.java:31)` ...impossible.. I just counted, there is only 27 lines in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class Fraction1
        {
            private int numerator;     
            private int denominator;   
        //no return type in constructor
            public Fraction1(int n, int d)
            {
                this.numerator = n;
                this.denominator = d;
            } 

            public void print()
            {
                System.out.println(numerator + "/" + denominator);
            }

            public Fraction1 add(Fraction1 other)
            {
    //Does nothing. What does saving the values in n and d give you. 
//Nothing. Hence your objects numerator and denominator 
//remains 0 and hence 0/0 gives your error
                int n = this.numerator * other.denominator +
                this.denominator * other.numerator;
                int d = this.denominator * other.denominator;
                return this;
            }

            //public void printAsDouble()
            //{
            //  this.printAsDouble();
            //  System.out.println((double)(numerator)/(double)                (denominator));
            //}
        }

x.add(c).add(d);
```

So x is an empty object i.e numerator and denominator = 0.
I use the add function, but it does not modify my x object and it remains the same. In the end, i call print and it should always print 0/0.

As per the error you are getting, check your command line arguments, they must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
(double)((numerator)/(denominator))
```

Comment: he is just printing that, wouldn't matter. He is never dividing it actually

Comment: He said the problem is in the commented code? //public void printAsDouble()
    //{
    //  this.printAsDouble();
    //  System.out.println((double)(numerator)/(double)                (denominator));
    //}

Comment: Okay. I tried everyone's suggestions and no change. Finally I got everything back to where it just does the addition but I still can't find the correct syntax or narrow down a reason for not being able to convert the sum of those fractions to a double. Thanks everyone for your help. Let me know what you can dig up if you're still trying. I noticed I got a down vote. Whatever. I'm trying. I think I was very clear with my problem.